# How to achieve stickyheader functionality like instagram in my grouped tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I need to implement the sticky header feature of the instagram application. I have a grouped tableview in which each section has single rows. What I tried so far is added a view to my tableview and unhide it when the scrolling starts and removing it when the scrolling reaches the top.

But how can I take cell image and title of the corresponding cell touching that header view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a view above the tableview.with whatever credentials you want in that.and then hide that view in the view didload of that class.And in the scrollviewdidscroll methode remove the navigation bar with an animation when `float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y`;is greater than zero.and unhide the view.and do the reverse when scrolloffset is equall to zero.